# Can I use SPARQLwrapper with a local copy of DBPedia?

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

The examples in the documentation suggest that I set the SPARQL endpoint in the following way:

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
```

Is there any way I can use SPARQLwrapper to search through a local copy of DBPedia rdf dataset?

Comment: "SPARQLWrapper is a wrapper around a SPARQL service". That means, you have to provide the service, e.g. load it into your local triple store.

Comment: Like @AKSW said, just load the data into a local service, and then point SPARQLwrapper at it.  You could use Jena's Fuseki, Virtuoso, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of the `SPARQLWrapper()` call is not DBpedia, per se (even though it may look like it), but a SPARQL endpoint.

Change `http://dbpedia.org/sparql` to your local SPARQL endpoint, e.g., `http://local-dbpedia.example.com/sparql` ... and you should be set.

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://local-dbpedia.example.com/sparql")
```